# Return based style analysis

Tags: performance, sas

I am trying to run Sharpe's return based style analysis in SAS. Its an optimization procedure where we have to minimise the varience of the error term (tracking error).

The equation is some what lke follows,

var(e) = Var (RFUND - VAR(sum (Wi.RSTYLEi))

I am just confused on how to state the objective function in the proc optmodel in SAS?